# vb.net font display with windows XP

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, windows-xp

I am writing an application in VB.net (using VS 2010) and I have to support XP (don't ask). The computer I am using to develop on is Windows7. My app looks perfect on my machine. When I run it on XP, the font doesn't look exactly like it does on 7. Basically it is the same font, just displayed a bit too small. So my text fields don't line up correctly in XP and there is too much space between the words.

I have tried different methods like using a privateFontCollection and using both custom fonts and regular windows fonts and they all have their own problems displaying exactly like they do in Windows 7.

Is there any trick to getting them to match? Is there anything I can do to make sure they display one way in 7 and another way in XP without having to check the OS every time I try to display something?

Thanks.

Comment: Check that you are using the same DPI setting in both Windows XP and Windows 7. If you are using different DPI settings your app can look different. Also, if you can post some screenshots, that will help us pinpoint the problem.

Comment: What font are you specifying? The default WinForm template uses a placeholder font that is mapped to the default dialogue font in each OS. This changed between XP and Win7. If you do layout relative to the font (eg. no pixel sizes) everything should line up.

Comment: Ove, Are you talking about setting the DPI within VS? If so, where would I do that? If not VS, then where?

Comment: I've tried Arial, tahoma, some custom fonts that I donwloaded, and a couple other windows fonts just to see what they would do. I can't post screen shots because I don't have the XP machine with me until Monday.

Comment: So Richard, you are saying if I don't specify a font, then windows will use a default font and everything should line up? I did line everything up by font and not by pixel.